# Strange behaviour in AppEngine Go app

Tags: json, google-app-engine, go

I have a Go (Golang) app that was deployed on AppEngine 96 days ago, with no changes since then.  About 12 hours ago I started getting a flood of the following errors:

> JSON failed to decode Google Play token claims (json: cannot unmarshal
>   bool into Go value of type string).

Has anyone had a similar problem, or has an idea what could have changed to cause this?

Comment: Maybe the API changed in the meantime? Or are they using a mixed field, which can be both a bool and a string and you are receiving bools now?

Comment: @seong That is exactly what happened.  Problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Google changed the response structure of the authentication API from a string (which was strange in the first place) to a bool.

My first assumption is that there is something wrong on my side, but for once I can say it was Google's fault.